# Реализация плана работы в 1С

Tags: 1с

С помощью каких объектов конфигурации вы бы реализовали хранение и слежение за выполнением такого плана в табличной форме ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Речь идет о том, что перечисленные сотрудники (вася, петя и т.п.) в течение года должны выполнить определенное количество документов (больших, малых и т.п.). Понимаю, что буду документы, их проведение + регистры = отчеты. А вот как хранить сам план с возможностью его просмотра и автоматическим заполнением не пойму

Answer (score 0):

Записью в таблице будет являться запись в документе, которая в свою очередь за счет движений попадет в регистр, а отчет уже выведет саму таблицу со строками из связки документ-регистр.

Answer (score 0):

Сам план можно хранить в справочнике и редактировать когда будет нужно. Либо так же в переодическом РС и брать информацию по периоду периода. Скорее всего РС будет правильнее